Can we change the colour of the icons in SharePoint from the library when using Quicklinks
Is it possible to change the icons used in SharePoint when adding in a Quicklink webpart?
Not matter what theme i used its always set to black.
With json formatting i know its possble to set a theme
Tkanks


What I'm seeing is that the theme is applied only when Tiles option in Quick Links Layout Options is selected. Maybe it is by design.

